# how to draw an undirected graph knowing only connections and weights

Tags: matrices, graph-theory, algorithms

I need to draw a complex graph on computer, but all I know are nodes connections and their weights. The problem is how to draw it clearly. Because I don't know [x,y] coordinates for each node, and what I tried so far, gives unsatisfactory results, which cannot be understood or seen correctly, and many nodes overlap and etc. Is there an algorithm which can tell me how to draw each node in a optimised way ? How I can do this?

Comment: You might try [grpahviz](https://www.graphviz.org/)

Comment: The easiest way would be to use somehting like Mathematica

Comment: http://graphonline.ru/en/   and    http://graphonline.ru/en/create_graph_by_matrix   and   https://www.nctm.org/Classroom-Resources/Illuminations/Interactives/Graph-Creator/   and    http://www.graphtheorysoftware.com/

Comment: https://networkx.github.io/ for python library very easy to use!!

Comment: Assuming that your question is mathematical, but not about which software to use to draw a graph (because you have asked it at Mathematics.SE) :-), I can say that there is a wide variety of graph drawing styles (for instance, straight-line or grid drawings) and algorithms (and even a special devoted [International Symposium on Graph Drawing and Network Visualization](http://www.graphdrawing.org/)). The choice of a good that highly depends on the graph properties (e.g. its size, sparseness, whether it is planar or not) and drawing purposes

Comment: (e.g., which drawing characteristics should be maximized or stressed and how a drawing should be related with the weights). So a priori, without knowing you specific problem and needs it is impossible for me to recommend you a concrete style and method. But if you specify them, I can ask a big specialist in graph drawing, [Alexander Wolff](http://www1.informatik.uni-wuerzburg.de/en/staff/wolff-alexander/) for relevant a short introduction and a brief survey of the topic.